# Processing interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1

Tags: processing

The various icons and buttons in the Processing Application(Visualisation application) interface are very, very small on a laptop with a 3200x1800px screen. The icons are difficult to see unless my nose is a few cm from the screen.

I've played around with adjusting the screen resolution and other settings in the operating system (Windows 8.1), which helps, but results in other applications appearing too large, and even then the Processing icons are uncomfortably small.

Is there any easy way to force larger icons? 
I also tried Compatibility view=>Disabled display Scaling on high DPI
Still it does not work. Any help would be appreicated??

Answer (score -1):

You should be able add your own icon to a sketch window:

```
ImageIcon titlebaricon = new ImageIcon(loadBytes("myicon.gif"));
frame.setIconImage(titlebaricon.getImage());
```

or

```
PImage icon = loadImage("myicon.gif");
frame.setIconImage((Image) icon.getNative());
```

via [Processing github wiki](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Export-Info-and-Tips)

For the editor itself how about creating a shortcut and adding your own custom hi-res icon to that ? (If you want to change the icon of an exe that should be do-able with simple software usually handling icons, but I'm not sure that's worth the effort (If it does, I'm sure you'll find plenty of exe icon switching programs out there))

If you want to change the size of the icons in the Processing Editor itself (e.g. Run,Stop,New,Open,Save,Export,etc.) you will need to edit the [Editor](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/94cc8b6f0bc31004fcf6738c759e8d36776980e3/app/src/processing/app/Editor.java) and recompile the Processing application.
If this is too much trouble, simply use the shortcuts:

- Run: Ctrl+R
- Stop: ESC
- New: Ctrl+N
- Open: Ctrl+O
- Save: Ctrl+S
- Export: Ctrl+E

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about icons within the application, not the icons used for launching the application.

Comment: I see, I've read the question in a hurry on the tube. The answer's updated now. Thanks for the heads-up